# Was the altar and the lampstand kept lit during Sabbath?

Tags: shabbat

Was the fire kept burning or was it put out during Sabbath? https://biblehub.com/interlinear/exodus/35-3.htm

Comment: I fixed that for you. The translation for menorah is lampstand. I am not writing in Hebrew.

Comment: Personally I would translate menorah as candelabra. In any event I think menorah is a proper noun and can be written as is. It's even in [Oxford English dictionaries](https://languages.oup.com/google-dictionary-en/).

Comment: Could you please clarify why it would be put out on the Sabbath? We're not Karaites...

Comment: https://biblehub.com/interlinear/exodus/35-3.htm .I don't think you speak for everyone using this website regarding their views...

Comment: @PabbleGoobs I hope I didn't offend you. I believe the default understanding of most users on this site is not in line with Karaites beliefs

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Shmos 35:3](https://www.chabad.org/library/bible_cdo/aid/9896/showrashi/true#v3)

> You shall not kindle fire in any of your dwelling places on the Sabbath day."

First of all, only the Karaites forbid leaving a flame already burning.

Second, this is a commandment that applies only outside the Temple. The commands to bring the sacrifices and keep the menorah burning are explicit in the Torah and thus apply on the Sabbath as well. The menorah is relit every night and left burning until the following night (even Friday night - the Sabbath). There is an explicit command to maintain the fire on the altar all day, from the time it must be rekindled every morning until all the sacrifices have been burned.